# Creating tables in a pptx using Apache POI

Tags: java, powerpoint, apache-poi

I'm trying to create some slides with Apache POI and everything is OK, except tables. 
I use the same code as one of their [tutorials](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/Tutorial4.java) and the result is (in my code and excuting the Tutorial) a single,empty and unformatted cell. Also, with this tables OpenOffice is unable to open the file (and Powerpoint shows that single cell).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved it and I'll post here for future reference

I had to replace the poi-ooxml-schema-3.8-20120326.har with [ooxml-schema-1.1.jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca:%22ooxml-schemas%22) and everything was OK